# SharePoint homepage template type

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a fresh installation of SharePoint 2010. Playing around with it I accidentally set the home page to a Document Store (I was logged in as admin). How can I reset the homepage to display the original options before I converted it to a Document Store?

I tried `Site Actions -> Reset site definition`, but that didn't help.

**Solution**

SharePoint does not allow site definitions to be changed. The page that allows site definitions to be selected ([YOUR-SITE]/_layouts/templatepick.aspx) says:

> Template Selection A site template determines what lists and features
>   will be available on your new site. Select a site template based on
>   the descriptions of each template and how you intend to use the new
>   site. Many aspects of a site can be customized after creation.
>   However, the site template cannot be changed once the site is created.

Answer (score 1):

To select a page to be the home page, navigate to that page and click on the Page ribbon. You will see 'Make Homepage' button in the 'Page Actions' section of the ribbon then, confirm the action in the pop-up prompt that shows up.

Comment: I don't want to set a new homepage, i only want to revert back to the view displayed for the first time logging in...i.e. when the homepage had not been set to a type of 'Document Store'.  From memory there was some kind of options widget on the right-hand-side of the page which listed site types (e.g. Document Store).